# How to determine numeric value from vsam file for packed PIC cobol clause without writing a cobol program?

Tags: code-analysis, cobol, vsam

I've used a utility package (vsmr) to read the values for a VSAM file and I have the copybook source code available to me.

If I have definitions like below (please excuse the formatting)

```
01 RECORD
   05 RECORD-X PIC S9(3)V99 COMP-3
   05 RECORD-Y PIC S9(3)V99 COMP-3
   05 RECORD-Z PIC S9(3) COMP-3
   05 RECORD-ALPHA PIC X(10)
```

and I have the following in data

00 20 0C 01 10 0C 01 00 0C

How do I determine the numeric value for RECORD-X?

I assume RECORD-X takes 3 bytes and the values 00 20 0C correspond to the value of RECORD-X, but I do not know how to convert this to a human readable value (algorithmically, not necessarily programatically).

I would also assume the values 01 10 0C correspond to the value for RECORD-Y.  Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: You have a conflict between the data you show for RECORD-Z and the value. RECORD-z is only two bytes long (as shown) and for two bytes, you don't have a trailing operational sign, so using the field in a program could easily cause an "abend" (a program failure). It is most likely you have the definition incorrect, as there is a correct-looking value in the low-order nybble of the following byte.

Comment: Reading is easy. A Binary Coded Decimal, is decimals in a "binary" field. For COMP-3/PACKED-DECIMAL the sign is in the low-order half-byte, as i@cschneid described. Normally only see C (positive) D (negative) and F (unsigned, treated as positive),  but the other values mentioned are possible, so you can't *just* ignore them if you want to convert(I'd report them as failures). Decimal-points are always implied, so you need the data-description (the PICture clause) to determine how many, if any, decimal places there are. Anything after a V is a decimal-place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COMP-3 is an implementation of Binary Coded Decimal (BCD). Each nibble in a byte corresponds to a digit, with the last nibble holding the sign.  Where you have...

```
00 20 0C 01 10 0C 01 00 0C
```

...we can map the first three bytes to `RECORD-X` and have a value of +002.00.  Sign nibbles with a value of C, A, F, or E are arithmetically considered positive; sign nibbles with a value of B or D are arithmetically considered negative.  The decimal point is not encoded in the data, you must have the field definition to know where it is.

IBM Enterprise COBOL has the concept of "preferred sign" which is C for positive and D for negative.  There are optimizations you can take advantage of if you are certain your data is all "preferred sign."

Your assumption about `RECORD-Y` is correct, its value is +11.00.

If you are writing COBOL, you need implement no algorithm to convert this to a human readable value, simply `MOVE RECORD-X TO RECORD-X-DISPLAY` where `RECORD-X-DISPLAY` is defined with `PIC +999.99`.

Comment: Since the last nibble is C, I assume that means positive versus D if negative?  Also is 00 20 0 then equivalent to 002.00?  Would that mean RECORD-Y is 11.00?  If you could expand the answer a little bit to cover this, then I'm willing to accept this as the answer for my question.

Comment: According to your copybook, Recor-X & Record-Y are 3 digits before the decimals. and yes, C means positive(remember : C as credit, D as debit). So 00 21 5C 01 23 8D 00 1C would read, with your grid, +002.15 -012.38 +001